# What's wrong with this recursive polymorphic C++1y lambda call?

Tags: c++, lambda, variadic-templates, c++14

I was playing around with polymorphic variadic lambdas on Clang and noticed that Clang doesn't like this one

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    auto append = [](auto &&cnt, auto &&me, 
                     auto &&a, auto &&p1, auto &&...p) -> decltype(auto) 
    { 
        if(sizeof...(p) > cnt) 
            return me(++cnt, me, a << p1, p..., 0);
        return a;
    };
    append(0, append, std::cout, 1, 2, 3, 4);
}
```

It's intended to putput "1234". A 0 is appended to the parameter list (and in turn one of the parameters from the front is taken away each time) and a counter watches when we need to stop because we would be hitting a dummy `0`.

But Clang complains about

```
fatal error: recursive template instantiation exceeded maximum depth of 256
```

In its backtract, most of the function frames are

```
main.cpp:6:20: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'main()::<anonymous class>::operator()<int &, <lambda at main.cpp:4:19> &, std::basic_ostream<char> &, int &, int &, int &, int>' requested here
            return me(++cnt, me, a << p1, p..., 0);
                   ^
```

This seems like a recursive function template that calls itself, and I can't see the infinite template instantiation madness. Can someone please shed some light? Does the Standard perpahs forbid recursion like that for lambdas?

Comment: @dyp ah thanks! please make it an answer and I will accept

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That should be [dcl.spec.auto]/11 (quoting n3797)

> If the type of an entity with an undeduced placeholder type is needed to determine the type of an expression,
>   the program is ill-formed. Once a `return` statement has been seen in a function, however, the return type
>   deduced from that statement can be used in the rest of the function, including in other `return` statements.

So, by reverting the return-statements, the return type deduction can succeed:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    auto append = [](auto &&cnt, auto &&me, 
                     auto &&a, auto &&p1, auto &&...p) -> decltype(auto) 
    { 
        if(sizeof...(p) <= cnt) 
            return a;
        return me(++cnt, me, a << p1, p..., 0);
    };
    append(0u, append, std::cout, 1, 2, 3, 4);
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7f125ee6b2c37e29)

Comment: Change it e.g. to `sizeof...(p)+1` to get the output `1234` as expected.

Comment: @TemplateRex Editing has side-effects, so I sometimes comment if it's a minor remark.

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be it's looping forever trying to deduce your return type. When it sees `return me( ... )`, it tries to figure out what THAT function's return is, which is also `auto` which requires figuring out what `return me( ... )` is and so on.

Maybe try

```
if(sizeof...(p) <= cnt) return a;
return me(++cnt, me, a << p1, p..., 0);
```

or try `decltype(a)` as the return type.

I don;t have a 1y compiler handy at the moment, or I'd be able to say for certain.

Comment: @TemplateRex When I'm at work, I'm lucky SO gets through the firewall =/